# Crispy Django Forms

Tags: django-forms, django-views, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

I am Using Crispy form in Django, But now I like to change the text and style in the form of how to do it?

[image]

Suppose I like to change the camp Name to the Only Name, the Text is taken from Django Model, But I like to change here and also I want the text should be on left of text field not on top, How to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For horizontal forms see the docs here, same rules apply for bootstrap 4.

https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html?highlight=Inline#bootstrap3-horizontal-forms

To change the fields labels see the django docs

class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('name', 'title', 'birth_date')
        labels = {
            'name': 'Writer',
        }

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields